# PHPStorm > Switch language level to JSX Harmony

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

I'm getting this message in PHPStorm.

```
Switch language level to JSX Harmony
```

Why is PHPStorm giving me this message?

Comment: It's normally when you include some kind of html markup in a Javascript file. `<div>Something</div>` inside a string. Or you actually tried using JSX. Or maybe when it detects the appearance of React.

Answer (score 1):

It interprets whichever file you have open as JSX, the format used by [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/), and suggests you to change the syntax checker to interpret JSX instead of JS, which is what will happen if you click "switch".

In JSX, you can write a html-like syntax, which is precompiled into vanilla JS before runtime. If you try to write HTML inside vanilla Javascript, the syntax checker will think it's an errornous syntax, and code reformatting, syntax highlighting etc. will not work as expected.

Comment: He's asking why, not what it does.

Comment: Im answering to exactly that. It is interpreting the document as JSX, and is suggesting that he switches the syntax checker to JSX.